# The code is for returning the outlying even or odd number, everything works except for my numbers are returning with brackets, thanks

Tags: python

example of a problem would be [2,4,6,8,9]
the code should return 9, instead it returns [9]

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    even, odd = 0, 0
    outlier = []

    for num in integers:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd +=1
    if even > odd:
        for num in integers:
            if num % 2 != 0:
                outlier.append(num)
                return outlier
    else:
        if odd > even:
            for num in integers:
                if num % 2 == 0:
                    outlier.append(num)
                    return outlier
```

Comment: `return num` instead of `return outlier`.

Comment: Why do you need the `outlier` list? It will never have more than 1 element in it, since you return immediately after appending to it.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list of provided integers always contains exactly one odd or exactly one even number?

Comment: @ryan - what if your list is ```nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]```?   what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the list and printing the list. That's the reason
you can returning the num instead of the outlier list

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    even, odd = 0, 0
    outlier = []

    for num in integers:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd +=1
    if even > odd:
        for num in integers:
            if num % 2 != 0:
                outlier.append(num)
                return num
    else:
        if odd > even:
            for num in integers:
                if num % 2 == 0:
                    outlier.append(num)
                    return num
print(find_outlier([2,4,6,8,9]))
```

But still your code is fully mess. It's not gonna return more than one odd or even. I exactly don't know what you wanted to mean by this code. But this shortened code may help

```
def CheckEvenOrOdd(integers):
    even, odd= 0,0
    Evenlist=[]
    OddList=[]
    for num in integers:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            Evenlist.append(num)
            even += 1
        else:
            OddList.append(num)
            odd +=1
    if even > odd:
        return OddList
    else:
        return Evenlist

print(CheckEvenOrOdd([2,4,6,8,9,11]))
```

It's gonna return list so there is no problem with that